# how many data can be stored in BIG NUMBER in ethereum ? web3

Tags: ethereum, web3js

How many data can be stored in BIG NUMBER in web3 ethereum?

Can I store data as long as the following example?

```
ab10293819283019298283939283019a9b9c9a0b9e9a9b8d7b6a7d9ba7d98ba6d8b8a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum bits of information a solidity integer type can store is 256. In smart contract written in solidity there are int/uint types from 8 to 256 bits.

Comment: 256 bit ? or what .. ?